# An error occurred while connecting to Firefox ---> System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty

Tags: c#, selenium

I am working with selenium the last months. I use VS 2013 C#. Most of the time i am using webdriver.dll (2.39.0.0) for firefox (31.0.0.5310), because my testautomation (coded ui tests)
ran pretty stable with it. but now i get randomly this error:

*> **OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: An error occurred while connecting to Firefox ---> System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty**.*

> Result StackTrace:
>   at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)
>
> at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxExtension.Install(String profileDir) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\webdriver\Firefox\FirefoxExtension.cs:line 106
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile.InstallExtensions() in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\webdriver\Firefox\FirefoxProfile.cs:line 357
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile.WriteToDisk() in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\webdriver\Firefox\FirefoxProfile.cs:line 254
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.ExtensionConnection.Start() in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\webdriver\Firefox\Internal\ExtensionConnection.cs:line 90
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver.StartClient() in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\webdriver\Firefox\FirefoxDriver.cs:line 225
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver.StartClient() in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\webdriver\Firefox\FirefoxDriver.cs:line 231
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 88
>
> at Testcase1.UIMap.BrowserSettingsFF() in c:***************\UIMap.cs:line 609
>
> at Testcase1.UIMap.InitDriver() in c:***************\UIMap.cs:line 678

I run it on 2 devices working with TFS. On one device it happens much more often.
I could not figure out the problem by now. Has anyone the same problem?

Comment: I'd upgrade to the most recent selenium and firefox version.

Comment: How are you creating the instance of the driver?

Comment: i did some upgrades some months ago and had problems with stability, thats why i am working with this versions by now. but maybe i will try to upgrade again the latest selenium release. the trouble is, its my last days for this project, but i will forward it to my successor.

Comment: Any news about this error ? I'm expected same problem with Selenium 2.45